# Porque no se me estan guardando los registros en la base de datos?

Tags: laravel-7

Buenas no se porque cuando lleno el formulario para agregar contactos no me los guarda en la base de datos.

Mi migration de contactos es la siguiente:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('position');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idOwner');
            $table->foreign('idOwner')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('mobile_no');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Estas son mis rutas para ver y agregar contactos:

```
Route::prefix('contact')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/add', 'Backend\ContactController@add')->name('contacts.add');
        Route::post('/store', 'Backend\ContactController@store')->name('contacts.store');
        Route::get('/view', 'Backend\ContactController@view')->name('contacts.view');
    });
```

Y por ultimo este es mi metodo store en ContactController:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $contact = new Customer();
        $contact->name = $request->name;
        $contact->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $contact->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $contact->position = $request->position;
        $contact->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
        $contact->email = $request->email;
        $contact->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('contact.view');
    }
```

El error que obtengo es 'The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.' y si cambio la ruta en vez de poner get pongo post me da exactmente el mismo error pero diciendo que no soporta el Metodo GET

Antes de que pregunten, mi formulario de la vista esta o=con method="post" y action = "{{ route('contacts.store') }}"

Comment: ¿Y si agregaste el token?

Comment: También prueba limpiar la cache de rutas `php artisan route:clear`